# Can i receive messages with FCM without notification permission?

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to know if I can receive payload from FCM in my iOS app, even if the user doesn't allow notifications for my app. I don't want to show them as notifications, i just want to handle their payload.

Does background messaging work without permission?

Does foreground messaging work without permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase Cloud Messaging APNs interface uses the Apple Push Notification service (APNs) to send messages up to 4KB in size to your iOS app, including when it is in the background.

Notification permission **is required for both** background and foreground work (even if your push notification is a silent one i.e no notification needs to be displayed)

Comment: On iOS, macOS & web, before FCM payloads can be received on your device, you must first ask the users permission. Android applications are not required to request permission. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#requesting-permission-apple--web

Comment: just add the official documentation, even though it is FCM for Flutter documentation, but under the hood they are also the same for native iOS.  on Android, the FCM listeners will still be invoked even after I disabled the notification in phone settings, it just doesn't display it in the notification tray

Answer (score -1):

You still need the user to allow the notifications, later on, you can implement the handling as silent or not, up to you.

In order to receive the payload you need, it must come from a push notification.

Comment: Your answer is confusing, can you explain your answer? Does this mean that FCM only sends data using push notifications, which require permission from user?